# Running background thread(s) millions of times

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, backgroundworker

I am developing a WPF GUI (.net 3.5) that has a `BindingList` bound to a datagrid. I handle the `ListChangedEvent` of the `BindingList` and in that I perform an expensive linq query on the same `BindingList` and update certain properties in the linq result (**which raises and dispatches `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event on the GUI correctly when updated**).

My binding list may already have millions of records and the GUI at times may perform million of transactions (add or remove) on those records in a matter of few seconds. So each transaction will raise `ListChangedEvent` event.

This is where my GUI was impacting so I moved the linq check on background thread. But here is the deal...

1. To get consistent results I must spawn a new background thread on **each** `ListChangedEvent` received. This will cause millions to threads to be spawned in memory in few seconds... a very large bottleneck on memory.
2. I may use a single background worker but it cannot run a new async work until its finished, so we will have to wait on GUI thread. GUI will hang and thats again a problem!
3. I can check bgWorker.IsBusy() but that will **skip** many `ListChangedEvent` handled while the worker is busy thus loosing the integrity of the linq query.
4. Suppose I find a way out to tackle this issue discussed in point numbers 2 and 3 above, I should anyways rely on the **snapshot** of the million-records-collection at each asyc work I do. This will cause large number of local million record collections getting created and GCed, perhaps in a matter of few seconds...

So I am confused what solution will server me best...

**Existing Pseudo Code:**

```
  ....
  var bindingList = GetMillionsOfRecordsBindingList();
  bindingList.ListChanged += OnEachItemChanged;
  mydataGrid.ItemsSource = bindingList;      
  .... 

  private void OnEachItemChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      var currentStauses = GetCurrentStatuses();

      var matchedItems = from p in bindingList
      where p.RefID != null
      and curStauses.Any(status => status.Type == p.Status.Type) 
      select p;

      // We have checked that in production the matchedItems collection
      // less than hundred items updated with their statuses at a time. 

      foreach(var p in matchedItems)
      {
          p.ShowHighlightAnimation = true; //GUI runs animations on the updated items.
      }
  }
```

**My Proposed Pseudo Code:**

```
  private void OnEachItemChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      var bgWrkr = new BackgroundWorker(); 
      // This will spawn millions of threads
      // (even if they wait in threadpool we have million threads to finish)

      bgWrker.DoWork
         += (o, args) =>
           { 
               var listOfItems = args.Argument as List<MyItems>;
               var currentStauses = GetCurrentStatuses();

               var matchedItems = from p in bindingList
               where p.RefID != null
                     && curStauses.Any(status => status.Type == p.Status.Type) 
               select p;        

               foreach(var p in matchedItems)
               {
                    p.ShowHighlightAnimation = true; 
                    //GUI runs animations on the updated items.
               }
           };

       bgWrkr.RunWorkerAsync(bindingList.ToList());
   }
```

I know this code is equally bad.... Hence I am confused about the correct approach!

**Note:** *I cannot control the other process that performs these million transactions on the binding list. It may do so in few seconds or leisurely in a day. So the LINQ synchronization (that I am doing on the other thread) only at the end of that process is out of question.*

Answer (score 1):

The `BackgroundWorker` provides a nice simple interface to achieve background processing when you have a discrete piece of work to perform. It also has the nice feature that it provides an easy mechanism for updating controls via the UI thread. However, it is a little limited.

How about using the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5htx827.aspx)? This allows you to use numerous threads for performing tasks. You can send tasks to the thread pool via [QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx). You will, however, have to marshal updates back to the UI thread via `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @CilnE thx for the comments... but wouldnt threadpool queue the threads? Can it queue millions? What will be the impact? I guess then my creating new background worker on each changed event, apporach would also work as background worker itself internally uses threapool!

Comment: ThreadPool is designed for queuing big amount of tasks that needs to be run on limited quantity of threads.

Comment: @zabulus, Jon Skeet wrote this article http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/multithreading.html about how background worker uses threadpool internally and limitations of threadpool due to queueing and because of queueing it could itself may take long to finish the tasks... So is my GUI update guaranteed in expected duration?

Comment: GUI updates you are making from the body of your threads. In code you have comment: //GUI runs animations on the updated items. Here you must add form.BeginInvoke(<YourUpdateMethod>).

Comment: @zabulus as I said earlier, the property is bound to GUI via `INotifyPropertyChanged` and does not need `Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke` methods. `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event **in binding context** is thread safe. You can try for yourself, a sample multi threaded binding in WPF.